# Can I use Type N Mortar for acrylic bathtub?

Tags: basement, bathtub, installation

I am installing a Delta brand Acrylic bathtub in a basement on concrete. The instructions call for a mortar base but does not specify a specific kind.

Would Mastercraft brand “Type N Mortar” from Menards be fine?

Answer (score 1):

I’d use “Sakrete “ floor mortar because it’s used dry and can be compacted. See attached

https://www.sakrete.com/storage/components/Floor%20MudTDS_image_update_10-3-18.pdf